# SAS Using $ in Regex

Tags: regex, sas, sas-wps

I have a load of ID's that I want to flag if it ends in a slash and one or two digits. (/00, /01, /0)

Some ID's contain slashes in the middle that I don't want to flag.

So I want my result to be:

```
ID                Flag
P-MTP00197854/03    X
P-MTP00197868/02    X
P-MTP00197882/00    X
P-HMF00197730   
WI/B09/077094   
Q-MTP00197735   
Q-HMF00199313/0     X
```

I'd expect this function to do the job, but it doesn't detect anything:

```
if prxmatch("/\/\d{1,2}$/", ID) then Flag='X';
```

If I remove the $ sign, it detects what I want, but it also includes those ID's with slashes in the middle as it isn't starting at the end.

I've tested it on regex101 and it should work. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you try `prxmatch(prxparse("/\/\d{1,2}$/"), ID)`

Comment: Produces the same result unfortunately. Works without $, but not with.

Comment: I think in that case you can try `\/\d{1,2}\b` or `\/\d{1,2}(?!\d)` and if there should be no more slashes to the right `\/\d{1,2}\b(?!.*\/)`

Comment: That third one works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent a partial match, you can use a word boundary. To make sure that there is no more `/` to the right you can use a positive lookahead asserting not more occurrences of `/` to the right

```
\/\d{1,2}\b(?=[^\r\n\/]*$)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VJRsHP/1).

Or the other way around with a negative lookahead, asserting no `/` to the right:

```
\/\d{1,2}\b(?![^\/\r\n]\/)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hHAOrn/1).